# Is it possible to sign JWT with PGP key

Tags: jwt, gnupg, pgp

I couldn't find an information about in in Google. We are generating PGP key pairs using Bouncy Castle library and implementing our own "web of trust". I wonder if it is possible to use these keys for JWT also, or I need to use a PKI X509 certificates?
Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The signature and encryption algorithms officially supported [are listed here](http://www.iana.org/assignments/jose/jose.xhtml#web-signature-encryption-algorithms).
No signature or encryption algorithm using PGP is listed.

But nothing prevent you from implementing a new signature/encryption algorithm used by your server and clients.
AFAIK, there is no implementation at the moment that uses GPG.

From my point of view, you have to create a new [key type](http://www.iana.org/assignments/jose/jose.xhtml#web-key-types) (e.g. JWK with `kty=PGP`) and new `alg` (e.g. `alg=PGP`).

Comment: Don't think that's necessary or even appropriate. PGP is like JOSE/JWT in that it is a message format that uses lower level cryptographic primitives rather than itself being a signature or encryption algorithm (the 1st answer to this question explains it better than I can http://security.stackexchange.com/questions/1750/how-does-rsa-encryption-compare-to-pgp). If the PGP keys are using RSA (>2048) or EC (one of the curves that JOSE uses), then one should be able to use them directly with the corresponding JWT/JOSE algorithms like RS256 or ES256.